# Delete text in between HTML tags in vim?

Tags: html, vim, editor

I know

```
di<
```

will delete in an HTML tag itself.

Is there an easy way to delete text in between two tags?

```
<span>How can I delete this text?</span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 401, accepted):

`dit` will delete the text between matching XML tags.  (`it` is for "inner tag block".)

See `:h it` and `:h tag-blocks`.

Comment: And, of course, `cit` when you want to write immediately afterwards.

Comment: And the Surround plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) is awesome when you want to do things like change the surrounding tag (cst) from a <p> to a <div>, for example.

Comment: There is also dat (Delete A Tag block) which includes the actual tags. cit which is like dit but enters insert mode after. cat which is like dat but enters insert mode after. Also di" and di( for delete inner double quote and delete inner parenthesis respectively.

Comment: @KrisJenkins can you show a full example how to achieve that? I can only do that with quotes/brackets.

Comment: Also `vat` (or `vit`), followed by repeated `at` (or `it`) to progressively select surrounding tags . (Or `v2at`, etc). Then `d` to delete (etc).

Comment: @KrisJenkins You can use `ci<` to change within angled brackets.

Answer (score 37):

```
cit
ci"
```

Two of the best productivity enabler commands of vim.

I save a lot of time and effort with just those two.

Comment: `cit` is covered in this thread, but for posterity, `ci"` will delete up to the next `"` found. great for changing class names in html tags, like `<span id="really long annoying-id">` -- with cursor at first `"`, hit `ci"` and be dropped into inserting new characters between the quotes.

Comment: `ciw` is also useful as it deletes the current word; I use it more than `cit` and  `ci"` actually.

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi: `ci"` will actually delete the text to the left until the next quote and to the right until the next quote and then enter insert mode. `ct"` is actually the command to "delete up to the next " found". But yes, it behaves the same if the cursor is under the left quote.

Answer (score 12):

dit - delete inner tag, remains in command mode
cit - change inner tag, changes to edit mode

di" - delete inside ""
di' - delete inside ''

di( - delete inside ()
di) - delete inside ()

di[ - delete inside []
di] - delete inside []

di{  -delete inside {}
di} - delete inside {}

di< - delete inside <>
di> - etc

swap first letter `d` for `c`, if you want to be in edit mode after typing the command

Answer (score 8):

try **dt<** while the cursor is on the first character to delete. In your example the 'H'.

Comment: Also very useful for other situations, thanks! (thought I think it should be "dt<")

Comment: While this is technically true, it requires navigating to the first character you want to delete instead of just jumping anywhere into the line. But true is true. :-)

Answer (score 3):

(*cursor on first character to delete*)
**v/<[enter]d**

This solution starts on the first character, then enters visual mode ("v"). It then searches for the next start bracket ("/<"), and then press enter to exit the search.

At this point, your visual selection will cover the text to delete.  press d ("d") to delete it.

If I had to do this for a bunch of tags, I'd record the command and combine it with some other searches to make it repeatable.  The key sequence might look like this:

[*cursor on start of file*]
**qa/>[enter]lv/<[enter]dnq**

then press:

**20@a**

to do this for 20 tags

Comment: I used to use command like `c/<[enter]` a lot, in my "Vim life", but now I'm a bit regretful about that. You see, most of "Vi-mode" plugins for popular other editors/IDEs do not support this specific type of command. They support `cit`, `ci"`, `ct<`and however. So, I'm re-teaching again.

Answer (score -1):

This applies to wherever your cursor is:

### HTML

`dit` - for deleting tag content while still in command mode

`cit` - for deleting tag content, insert mode **(Preferred Way)**

### STRING

`dit` - for deleting string content which still in command mode

`ci"`/`ci'` - for deleting string content, insert mode **(Preferred Way)**

Answer (score -2):

If you're aiming to do the inverse of deleting text between flags, I suggest installing [Vim-Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and running `dst` which deletes the surround tag