# Delete text in between HTML tags in IdeaVim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

[Delete text in between HTML tags in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946188/delete-text-in-between-html-tags-in-vim) provides a wonderful, succint answer for VIM that doesn't seem to work in IdeaVim. Anyone know how to achieve this in IntelliJ IdeaVim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this mapping

```
nnoremap <Leader><Key> T>dt<
```

It should work even for IdeaVim.

More on

[`:h t`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#t)
[`:h T`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#T)

Comment: I added that text into my ~/.ideavimrc and it did not help me.  I tried to do a dit and it does not delete in between the tags.  What could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: What about `nnoremap <F3> T>dt<`? Now try to press the `F3` key while cursor is between the tags. Does it work? If you are not familiar with mappings in Vim, try to read from [Basic Mapping](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html) till [Leaders](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/06.html). It is explained there very nicely.