# Delete/copy/etc inside angle brackets not working in Vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, macvim

`di<` and `di>` are not working for me in either Visual Studio Code (Vim mode) or in MacVim.

`di(` and `di{` and `di[` are all working fine.

I've tried it with both my usual Finnish keyboard layout and with an English keyboard layout. No success with either.

Should this work straight out of the box, or am I going to have to customise my Vim to get it working?

**My setup**

- macOS Sierra – Version 10.12.6
- MacVim Custom Version 8.0.1376 (but completely uncustomised by me)
- Visual Studio Code 1.19.1

**Update – Partial fix**

This extension for Visual Studio Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select lets you select between angle brackets when in Vim insert mode. Not ideal as it's not a Vim solution, but it works well, and actually works great in conjunction with Visual Studio Code's multicursor.

Comment: I have no idea about Visual Studio Code but yeah, `i<`, `i>`, `a<`, `a>` have been available in Vim out of the box for a looooong time.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. But strange that MacVim isn't working either. I would expect that to work exactly like regular Vim.

Comment: MacVim works exactly like regular Vim. Your issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I worked out the answer. I was actually trying to delete text ***between*** an opening and closing HTML tag, so `hello world` from here:

`<div>hello world</div>`

I should have used `dit` as explained here: [Delete text in between HTML tags in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946188/delete-text-in-between-html-tags-in-vim)

Comment: Lesson to learn: if I'm having a problem and I can't find the answer already on SO, it's quite likely that I've just made a silly mistake myself, as happened here.